# Text view Visiblity is repeating automatically in recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-xml

In my app I have set text visiblity to invisible and i am using firebase database. So, if from my firebase databse permission is true the text view is set to visible. It is working but problem in in recycler view list items it is visible after every 8th item of list. Please check Screenshot for my problem

using log.d I have checked my items having permission true and ther result is shown true as i have given only one true value.

Here is the link to my screenshot
https://ibb.co/YDpfgxF

Menuadapter.java - my text view was "recommended"

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import static androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Constraints.TAG;

public class MenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MenuAdapter.menuViewHolder>{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<dish> dishes;

    public MenuAdapter(Context c , ArrayList<dish> p)
    {
        context = c;
        dishes = p;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public menuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.d(TAG ,"On Create View Holder: called");

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);

        return new MenuAdapter.menuViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull menuViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.dishname.setText(dishes.get(position).getDishname());
        holder.dishrate.setText(dishes.get(position).getDishrate());



        Picasso.get().load(dishes.get(position).getDishImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background).into(holder.dishImage);


        holder.dishImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, " : " + dishes.get(position).getDishImage() );
                Toast.makeText(context,"clicked on" + dishes.get(position).getDishname(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        boolean flag = dishes.get(position).getPermission();
        if (flag){
            Log.d(TAG," recommended : " + dishes.get(position).getDishname());
            holder.recommended.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dishes.size();
    }

    class menuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView dishname, dishrate, recommended;
        ImageView dishImage;


            public menuViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
            {
                super(itemView);
                dishname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dishname);
                dishrate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dishrate);
                dishImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dishImage);
                recommended = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recommended);

            }
        }

}
```

CardView.xml - textview id "recommended"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="8dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/dishname"
            android:textColor="@color/dishnamecolor"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Recommended"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:background="@color/recommended"
            android:id="@+id/recommended"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/dishrate"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/dishratecolor"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="end"

        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dishImage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

```
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=26KB, data=29KB
    After code cache collection, code=25KB, data=28KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
D/Constraints: On Create View Holder: called
D/Constraints: On Create View Holder: called
D/Constraints: On Create View Holder: called
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=57KB, data=60KB
I/art: After code cache collection, code=57KB, data=60KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
D/Constraints:  recommended : Chili Paneer(Dry)
```

Answer (score 1):

i didn't actually manage to understand your problem but i think it would be solve if you add an else after checking the status of permission like this

```
if (flag){
        Log.d(TAG," recommended : " + dishes.get(position).getDishname());
        holder.recommended.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        holder.recommended.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

 }
```

Comment: Sorry but i can not share the screenshot of my problem because I need at least 10 reputation   and I have tried this solution but this didn't worked for me

Comment: i think in your recyclerview everything looks good and it should work so maybe the problem is in the other thing do you log all your data and checked them all ?

Comment: Yes I have checked using log also...is there any way I can share screenshot with you maybe it was easy to understand my problem by that

Comment: maybe you can upload your screenshots in other website and put their link here

Comment: can you please send me your logs that you write too

Comment: it is just for one item in the onBindViewHolder log the data name and its status till we be sure the datas are completely ok

Comment: because i did something like you do here and it worked in all the time and i checked your code and there is no problem in it so i am so confused and i think your data in the list should have problem

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean flag = dishes.get(position).getPermission();
    if (flag){
        holder.recommended.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        holder.recommended.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment an answer, so Im creating this answer.

You should include this because as you know you are using a RecyclerView, is a component that recycle your item/view so probably is recycling an item that has the textview visible

```
boolean flag = dishes.get(position).getPermission();
    if (flag){
        holder.recommended.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        holder.recommended.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```